# Popup Screen doesn't work

Tags: java, blackberry, popup

For the code shown below, when I press the Options button (given by optionsButton variable) there is no popup screen appearing. What am I doing wrong ?

```
    optionsButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
        public void fieldChanged(Field arg0, int arg1) {
            PopupScreen popup = new PopupScreen(new VerticalFieldManager());
            popup.add(new LabelField("Hello!"));
            Border border = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(
            new XYEdges(), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT);
            popup.setBorder(border);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to push the popup screen as Anzy_ suggested

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
optionsButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field arg0, int arg1) {
                PopupScreen popup = new PopupScreen(new VerticalFieldManager());
                popup.add(new LabelField("Hello!"));
                Border border = BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(
                new XYEdges(), Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT);
                popup.setBorder(border);

                Uiapplication.getUIapplication.pushScreen(popup);
            }
        });
```

Comment: And when you're done with your pop up screen you can remove it the same way. Use **Uiapplication.getUIapplication.popScreen(popup);**